# Sidebar not displaying properly in Opera

Tags: html, css, opera

Even on my very best days I am absolutely dismal at tracking down browser display issues.

In Opera, the left-hand sidebar on this page ( http://www.taysf.org/about ) is not displaying properly.  In every other browser, the sidebar has an orange-stripe-tan-block background, and for a reason I can not fathom that background does not display in Opera.

Do you have any idea why?  Will you take pity on me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An excerpt from your page (whitespace removed):

```
(...)
<input type="hidden" name="log" id="edit-log" value=""  />
</div>
</div></form>

</div>
</div></form>
<ul class="topnav">
(...)
```

See that second `</div></form>`? You have closed one div too many (div#page, to be exact; also, you tried to close a non-existing form). Opera did what you told it to do, closed the div#page, therefore div#content was not inside div#page, thus no background was shown under it. Other browsers saw the mismatched tags and guessed what you had in mind (in this case, successfully).

Comment: BRILLIANT!  Actually there were two forms, so the second closing was (in some bizarre sense) correct.  But form-in-a-form was a typo and was causing the error.  Thank you!